# Allowing users to create multiple list in Python

Tags: python, list

I want to user to input information and print out the total list. However, when the user input another list it only prints out the first list. How can I make the program print the users total input. Here's my code.

```
listing = []


class Car:
    def __init__(self, ownerName=None, model=None, make=None, price=None):
        self.ownerName = ownerName
        self.model = model
        self.make = make
        self.price = price

    def input(self):
        print "Please update car info \n"
        while True:
            i = 0
            listing.append(Car(raw_input("Owner Name"), raw_input("Model?"), raw_input("Make?"), raw_input("Price?")))
            print "Updated"
            print listing[i].ownerName, listing[i].model, listing[i].make, listing[i].price
            addOn = raw_input("Continue? (Y/N)")
            if addOn.lower() == "y":
                i += 1
                continue
            else:
                break

    # search a car and print its information. Exit when user input is 'exit'

def menu():
    x = Car()
    print "PLease choose an option (1-4):\n"
    choice = raw_input("1) input\n" \
          "2) change price and owner\n" \
          "3) search a car and print info\n" \
          "\"exit\" Exit")

    if choice == "1":
        x.input()
    elif choice == "2":
        print "Price"
    elif choice == "3":
        print "Search and Print info"


menu()
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you reset `i` on each iteration of your `while` loop.

Move the line:

```
    i = 0
```

to the line *before* the `while True:`

That should fix the immediate problem, however, your code uses an unusual design. You should not create a `Car` object in order to create further instances of `Car`s which are then inserted into a global list.

At a minimum you could make `input()` a static method and have it return a list of `Car` instances to the caller. Then you can do away with the global `listing` variable. Also, you don't actually need to keep a counter in `i` you can just use `-1` as the subscript to access the last item in the list:

```
    @staticmethod
    def input(listing=None):
        if listing is None:
            listing = []

        print "Please update car info \n"
        while True:
            listing.append(Car(raw_input("Owner Name"), raw_input("Model?"), raw_input("Make?"), raw_input("Price?")))
            print "Updated"
            print('{0.ownerName} {0.model} {0.make} {0.price}'.format(listing[-1]))
            addOn = raw_input("Continue? (Y/N)")
            if addOn.lower() != "y":
                break

        return listing
```

Using a static method is good here because `input()` is related to `Car` objects so it makes sense to package that function with the class.

Now you can call `input()` without creating an instance of a `Car`. In your `menu()` function remove the `x = Car()` and change `x.input()` to `listing = Car.input()`. Or, if you want to append to an existing "listing" list, call `Car.input(listing)` which will append new input to `listing`. You can then print the returned list to see all user input:

```
def menu():
    print "PLease choose an option (1-4):\n"
    choice = raw_input("1) input\n" \
          "2) change price and owner\n" \
          "3) search a car and print info\n" \
          "\"exit\" Exit")

    if choice == "1":
        listing = Car.input()
        # print out all user entered cars
        for car in listing:
            print('{0.ownerName} {0.model} {0.make} {0.price}'.format(car))
    elif choice == "2":
        print "Price"
    elif choice == "3":
        print "Search and Print info"
```

Comment: How do I print out the total list instead of one at a time?

Comment: @Maxwell: where do you want to print it? After all input has been collected, or do you want to print the whole list after each input?

Comment: @Maxwell: I've updated the answer to show how you could print all of the cars after they have been entered. Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

@mhawke's answer should fix your problem. However, I do not like the idea of creating objects of a class from one of its functions. Check the edited code below.

```
listing = []


class Car:
    def __init__(self, ownerName=None, model=None, make=None, price=None):
        self.ownerName = ownerName
        self.model = model
        self.make = make
        self.price = price

def input_car():
    print "Please update car info \n"
    i = 0
    while True:
        listing.append(Car(raw_input("Owner Name"), raw_input("Model?"), raw_input("Make?"), raw_input("Price?")))
        print "Updated"
        print listing[i].ownerName, listing[i].model, listing[i].make, listing[i].price
        addOn = raw_input("Continue? (Y/N)")
        if addOn.lower() == "y":
            i += 1
            continue
        else:
            break

    # search a car and print its information. Exit when user input is 'exit'

def menu():
    #x = Car()
    print "PLease choose an option (1-4):\n"
    choice = raw_input("1) input\n" \
          "2) change price and owner\n" \
          "3) search a car and print info\n" \
          "\"exit\" Exit")

    if choice == "1":
        input_car()
    elif choice == "2":
        print "Price"
    elif choice == "3":
        print "Search and Print info"


menu()
```

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up the code a little bit. I should work now. Option 3 gives you a complete listing of all cars so far, so youhave an example to build on.

```
listing = []

class Car:
    def __init__(self, ownerName=None, model=None, make=None, price=None):
        self.ownerName = ownerName
        self.model = model
        self.make = make
        self.price = price

    #to have a useful method for our example I overwrite the __str__ method from object
    def __str__(self):
        return ",".join([self.ownerName, self.model, self.make, self.price])


#input does not handle aspects of car, therefore it should be not a method of car
def input():
    print "Please update car info \n"
    while True:
        # there is no need for 'i' so I removed it
        car = Car(raw_input("Owner Name"),
                  raw_input("Model?"),
                  raw_input("Make?"),
                  raw_input("Price?"))
        listing.append(car)
        print "Updated"
        print car #possible since __str__ is overwritten
        addOn = raw_input("Continue? (Y/N)")
        if addOn.lower() == "n":
            break

def menu():
    keep_running = True
    #added a while loop so the user stays in the program until he types 'exit'
    #changed option '3' to have a working example to build on
    while keep_running:
        print "PLease choose an option (1-4):\n"
        choice = raw_input("1) input\n" \
                           "2) change price and owner\n" \
                           "3) list all cars\n" \
                           "\"exit\" Exit")

        if choice == "1":
            input()
        elif choice == "2":
            print "Price"
        elif choice == "3":
            print "\n".join(map(str, listing))
        elif choice == "exit":
            keep_running = False

menu()
```